# Special hover effect for all right elements

Tags: hover, tooltip, unique, effect

How do I make all right elements to have special hover effect - tooltip should appear on left side instead of right.

```
.wrapper:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
      -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
       -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
        -o-transform: translateY(0px);
           transform: translateY(0px);
    z-index:1000;
}
```

[**DEMO jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vxtq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML tags and CSS were both changed quite a bit so please see my DEMO below:

I created this Pure JS for adjusting z-index onmouseover and onmouseout, to be put in the head:

```
function onRoll(cl, cond) {
    if (cond === 1) {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
        for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
            element[i].style.zIndex = '1000';
        }
    } else if (cond === 2) {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName(cl);
        for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
            element[i].style.zIndex = '10';
        }
    }
}
```

DEMO: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/zQJsx/)

Comment: That make tooltip slide left, but I need only right elements to have tooltips that slide to left (for responsiveness) 
P.S: Vote UP requires 15 reputation, I will as soon as I have 15

Comment: Okay thanks for the reputation points explanation. I don't think this can be done without JS. I have an idea of how to go about it but would want a better explanation of what you're looking to do. See my latest fiddle for an idea of why you need js. http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/6K28y/

Comment: Thank you, so I'am working on [**my website**](http://pivvit.do.am/)  and this is used for team part - so when browser window is smaller - biographies will not fit, so they should go on left like [**here**](http://leadedgecapital.com)

Comment: @VitaliyHayda Thanks for clarification! I believe that should do it. Please don't forget about going back to help me when you can.

Comment: It doesn't work as I need... Last 3 are alway going to left, even if there is enough space for them to go right... anyway thank you